# GMail Filters not working

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have been receiving a lot of spam with the sender ending in something like this: `@kmfiadyzlf4ayelp.com`

Setting up filters isn't working because the domain is constantly "randomized" i.e. never the same twice, except that there is always yelp.com after the random string.

I tried using `@*yelp.com` and `*yelp.com` but it's not working.

Question is, how can I filter messages where the sending domain is semi-random like this and never the same twice?